# Как отключить шаблонизатор в Beego на определённом участке?

Tags: golang, шаблонизаторы, beego

Как отключить шаблонизатор в `Beego` на определённом участке?

Нужно отключить символы `{{ }}`, т.к. ещё есть `angularjs`, который использует их.

В `Twig` на `php` использовал `{%VERBATIM%} ....  {%endverbatim%}` и на этом участке, он вырубался. А что делать в `beego`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно изменить везде

---

Go uses {{ and }} as the default template tags. In the case that these tags conflict with other template tags as in AngularJS, we can use other tags. To do so, add these to the configuration:

- beego.TemplateLeft = "<<<"
- beego.TemplateRight = ">>>"

Comment: было бы замечательно, если бы вы перевели свой ответ на русский язык.